# localStorage checker not working when it looks fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a script on one part of my domain that sets the *localStorage*:*did* to *true*, and then send them to another part of my domain.

The page, which the viewer was sent to, checks to see if the *did* is *true*, and it is, but for some reason the function that starts if *did* is *true* does not work (but I have used that function a few days ago, so it works).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var is = localStorage.getItem('did');
       
       if (is == 'true') {
           
        localStorage.setItem('did','false');
        
        window.alert("ok")
        
        $.get('give.php' , {} , function(response){
         //window.alert(response);
        });   
        
       } else {
        window.alert("no")  
       }
     });
```

This is the checker. I don't think there is something wrong with it, but if I am mistaken, please tell me.

*localStorage.setItem('did','true');*

This is from the original page which sets *did* to *true*. I'm pretty sure that's how you do it.

When logging *did* on the other page, it comes out as *true*, but why is the *if* *function* not firing?

Comment: does function trigger on the same subdomain or across multiple subdomains?

Comment: I fixed it, the jQuery *on ready* was holding it back.